# xamarin studio is not downloading

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to make Android app using Xamarin Studio with Visual Studio 2013 by watching tutorials of ManzoorTheTrainer. I don't know why it is not downloading.
When I download Xamarin Studio by default it opens in VS 2013, but not an Exe file and gives an error list(dialogue box).
Can anyone please help me to sort out this problem?

Link of Android Tutorials:

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yb0BrUh-kh8][1]

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 has Xamarin built into it. Try this instead

Comment: ok thanks a ton!!! but i want to know the reason why it is not working with vs 2013.

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: I get a dialogue box with the list of errors...

Comment: Well, thanks a ton!!! I'll install VS 2015. :)